# Dataframe not being converted to a vector

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I'm trying to simply convert a dataframe to a vector.  Here's a sample:

```
mydataframe <- data.frame(1:4,5:8,9:12)  #create data frame
myvector <- as.vector(mydataframe)
class(myvector)  #this is not a vector
```

Answer (score 0):

For that type of dataframe, you can use `unlist` for creating a vector that includes names and `unname(unlist())` to remove the names. Such as:

```r
mydataframe <- data.frame(1:4,5:8,9:12)  #create data frame
myvector <- unname(unlist(mydataframe)) #create vector from dataframe

myvector
is.vector(myvector)
```

`unlist` works in this case because it simplifies the dataframe into a list structure while `as.vector` only removes the attributes. See [Andrew MacDonald's data structure posts](https://github.com/aammd/UBCadv-r/wiki/01:-Data-Structures) for more information on why `unlist` is sometimes preferred over `as.vector`

Comment: Thanks @JGreenwell, this solution works, but I guess I'm confused with _why_ you need to unlist the dataframe in the first place. Is the case with all dataframes that you're trying to convert to a vector?

Comment: by "removing attributes" do you mean removing columns to form a line list vector?   Also, "mydataframe" was a data frame, not a list, correct?  So I guess I'm still confused. Thanks.

Comment: Yes on the first. Typo in the second which is fixed now

Comment: Thanks @JGreenwell
You mentioned that "as.vector() removes the attributes (i.e. columns)".  However, "myvector" looks exactly the same as "mydataframe" in my original code.  It looks as though nothing changed at all. Can you please clear this up for me?  Is there anything unique about "mydataframe" that causes as.vector() to do this? Thanks

Comment: A `list` is also a vector

Comment: @DavidArenburg if you do class(myvector) it is a "dataframe", not a "list".

Comment: I'm not talking about that, just in general. Try `is.vector(list(a=2))` for instance.

Comment: @DavidArenburg can you explain why "mydataframe" can't be converted to a vector with as.vector()?

Comment: I wonder if read the documentation of `as.vector`. An (failed) attempt to coerce a `data.frame` to a vector is the first example there!

Comment: @DavidArenburg I'm confused in the first example for ?as.vector, it lists this code: `df <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 5:7)
as.vector(data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 5:7), mode = "numeric")` 
This results in the error: _Error in as.vector(data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 5:7), mode = "numeric") : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'_ 

What does this mean?  What is R trying to say?